# Prove or disprove that Arg(zw)=Arg(z)+Arg(w)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I talked to my professor and they said that it can be disproven using an example, specifically using a picture to explain why it statement is false. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What if $w=z=-1$?

Comment: @Nixie777 True/False $\cos(\theta)=\cos(\beta) \implies \theta = \beta$.

Comment: You've reposted the same question at least twice now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the version that lives in $(-\pi , \pi]$, "Arg" tells you how far you are from the positive real axis, angle-wise. The product of two complex numbers can be much closer than the factors originally were. Try drawing a unit circle.

Comment: `Arg tells you how far you are from the positive real axis, angle-wise` "*how far*" in what sense? $\,\operatorname{Arg}(zw) \equiv \operatorname{Arg}(z)+\operatorname{Arg}(w) \pmod{2 \pi}\,$, so the geometric angle with the real axis is the same between the two sides.

Comment: How far in the sense of the distance along the unit circle.

Comment: But points $e^{i 0}$ and $e^{i 2 \pi}$ on the unit circle are the same, so the `distance along the unit circle` is $\,0\,$.

Comment: Indeed, and Arg is $0 $ for both. For instance Arg is $\frac {\pi}{2}$ for $i$ because you walk that long (a fourth of the perimeter) to reach it from 1. The only thing is you add a minus sign if the shortest path involves turning backwards (clockwise in this case).

Comment: `only thing is you add a minus sign if the shortest path involves turning backwards` That sounds built on the assumption that the range of the principal value $\,\operatorname{Arg}\,$ is defined to be $\,(-\pi,\pi]\,$, but fails if the range is defined as $\,[0,2 \pi)\,$, which is another popular choice. You could mention that in the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: That's right. I edited.